VS Code Remote SSH "Setting up SSH Host <hostname>l: Waiting for port forwarding to be ready"
I have never had issues connecting to a particular remote host until two days ago when the connections stopped working.
The Output>Remote-SSH log says I am connecting to the host, because I see this in the log
[09:34:33.197] > 63ffd590a635: running
> Script executing under PID: 2924742
> Found existing installation at /home/blaylock/.vscode-server...
> Starting VS Code CLI...

but it doesn't finish the connection and the "notification" dialogue says
Setting up SSH Host <hostname>: Waiting for port forwarding to be ready

I haven't changed anything on my end (and I'm able to connect to other hosts without issue).
Could something have changed on the host side preventing the connection? Something related to port forwarding?
FWIW, I also tried with these suggested settings for troubleshooting, but they had no affect
"remote.SSH.showLoginTerminal": true,
"remote.SSH.useLocalServer": false

Thanks for any tips.
